# Python Threading inconsistent execution time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

- Using the `threading` library to accelerate calculating each point's neighborhood in a points-cloud.  By calling function `CalculateAllPointsNeighbors` at the bottom of the post.
  The function receives a search radius, maximum number of neighbors and a number of threads to split the work on. No changes are done on any of the points. And each point stores data in its own `np.ndarray` cell accessed by its own index.
- The following function times how long it takes `N` number of threads to finish calculating all points neighborhoods:

  ```
  def TimeFuncThreads(classObj, uptothreads):
      listTimers = []

      startNum = 1
      EndNum = uptothreads + 1

      for i in range(startNum, EndNum):
          print("Current Number of Threads to Test: ", i)
          tempT = time.time()
          classObj.CalculateAllPointsNeighbors(searchRadius=0.05, maxNN=25, maxThreads=i)
          tempT = time.time() - tempT
          listTimers.append(tempT)

      PlotXY(np.arange(startNum, EndNum), listTimers)
  ```

  - The problem is, I've been getting very different results in each run. Here are the plots from 5 subsequent runs of the function `TimeFuncThreads`. The `X` axis is number of threads, `Y` is the runtime. [image: Graphs]   First thing is, they look totally random. And second, there is no significant acceleration boost.

I'm confused now whether I'm using the `threading` library wrong and what is this behavior that I'm getting?

---

- The function that handles the threading and the function that is being called from each thread:

  def CalculateAllPointsNeighbors(self, searchRadius=0.20, maxNN=50, maxThreads=8):

  ```
      threadsList = []
      pointsIndices = np.arange(self.numberOfPoints)
      splitIndices = np.array_split(pointsIndices, maxThreads)

      for i in range(maxThreads):
          threadsList.append(threading.Thread(target=self.GetPointsNeighborsByID,
                                              args=(splitIndices[i], searchRadius, maxNN)))

      [t.start() for t in threadsList]
      [t.join() for t in threadsList]



  def GetPointsNeighborsByID(self, idx, searchRadius=0.05, maxNN=20):
      if isinstance(idx, int):
          idx = [idx]

      for currentPointIndex in idx:
          currentPoint = self.pointsOpen3D.points[currentPointIndex]
          pointNeighborhoodObject = self.GetPointNeighborsByCoordinates(currentPoint, searchRadius, maxNN)
          self.pointsNeighborsArray[currentPointIndex] = pointNeighborhoodObject
          self.__RotatePointNeighborhood(currentPointIndex)
  ```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a result of other things on the system like antivirus or other software impacting the run time?

Comment: As a side note: don’t use a list comprehension for side effects, only to build lists. If you were doing that to save space, you can write a trivial `for` statement as a one-liner and it’s shorter, not longer. If you were doing that because you heard listcomps are faster, they’re faster than calling `append` on each value, but they’re slower than not building a list at all.

Comment: Where is the time being spent? From a quick glance it looks like it’s probably inside that `__RotatePointNeighborhood` method you haven’t shown us. Wherever it is, is each thread sticking to its own segment of the shared array, or are they all trying to read (or, worse, write) overlapping segments?

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the list comprehension tip. All points write to the same `np.ndarray`. Although each point writes only to its own index. e.g., `p1` writes to `array[1]`. And since there are no overlapping points between the threads, and every point's neighborhood is calculated once, I assume this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It pains me to be the one to introduce you to the [Python Gil](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Is a very nice feature that makes parallelism using threads in Python a nightmare.

If you really want to improve your code speed, you should be looking at [the multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: I've tried doing `if idx[0]==0: {print("Sleep") time.sleep(5)} else: print("No sleep")` in `GetPointsNeighborsByID` function entrance, so only the first thread sleeps. Meaning that if it's paused, all subsequent threads would be paused - assuming they aren't running in parallel. However, using `maxThreads=4` I'm getting the output: Sleep, No Sleep, No Sleep, No Sleep. Instantly, without the 5 seconds wait. How would that be explained?

Comment: Threads **do** run in parallel...**kind of**. The `GIL` prevents multiple threads to execute python bytecode at once. I/O operations and native libraries don't have that problem. When you call `time.sleep` that thread goes to sleep and the next one starts up executing **bytecode** until it blocks or executes native code (that's why you keep getting ouput BTW)